# How to get SQL scripts generated by Code First Identity?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, identity

i need to deploy a website but in my tests i used code first approach mapping some tables to use Identity. But in the oficial enviroment i cannot create like this. I need to send the scripts to the db admins. 
theres a way to get it in the debug mode while im creating the tables for the first time?

Comment: Why can't you script your database and give them the SQL scripts?

Comment: @Maess God, i completly forget this. Sorry, ill delete the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DbContext` class doesn't provide a method to generate the database script, but the underlying `ObjectContet` does. You can get to the `ObjectContext` by casting the `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter`:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
string dbScript = objectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```